# Concatenate text from multiple rows and columns into a single text string in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nlp, nltk

[Picture of raw excel file format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ovKI0.png)

[image]

Attached picture reference for how my raw excel data looks like. Loaded into pandas dataframe. Each message is spread across multiple columns with occasional blank cells in between each column. Also, the separator for each message is 2 consecutive empty rows. To combine the message, I merged all 5 columns :

```
df['New Column'] = df['Column1'].astype(str) + df['Column2'].astype(str) + df['Column3'].astype(str) + df['Column4'].astype(str) + df['Column5'].astype(str)
```

The problem now is : -

1. How do I cluster each message into a single cell / pandas row because right now, the one message (E.g Message 1) can and may spread over a few rows
2. How do I format the messages using 2 empty rows as a seperator ?
3. After merging 5 columns into 1, there are many NaN values which I'm not sure what's the best way to handle given by very complicated and messy data structure.

Essentially, this is the desired output [image: Desired output]

Hope I'm clear enough, thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: [Please don't post images of code/data (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['Message 1: asd asd','asd','','Message 2:',''],'col2':['not','asd','asd','asd','asd'],'col3':['smoke', 'black','asd','asd','asd']})
df

                 col1 col2   col3
0  Message 1: asd asd  not  smoke
1                 asd  asd  black
2                      asd    asd
3          Message 2:  asd    asd
4                      asd    asd

result = ['Message'+x for x in df.apply(' '.join, axis=1).sum().split('Message')][1:]
df_result = pd.DataFrame(result)
df_result

                                                   0
0  Message 1: asd asd not smokeasd asd black asd asd
1                         Message 2: asd asd asd asd
```

Answer (score 0):

My idea is split first column by `:` and [`Series.str.partition`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.partition.html) to helper `DataFrame`, then create groups only by `Mesage` values by forward filling:

```
df1 = df['Column1'].str.partition(':')
m = df1[1].eq(':')
df1[2] = df1[2].where(m, df1[0])
df1[0] = np.where(m, df1[0].add(': '), np.nan)
df1[0] = df1[0].ffill()
print (df1)
             0    1           2
0  Message 1:     :   Please do
1  Message 1:            nearby
2  Message 2:     :     Parking
3  Message 2:   NaN         NaN
4  Message 3:     :
```

Then assign values of `Message`s to index of original and to first columns:

```
df['Column1'] = df1[2]
df.index = df1[0]
```

So possible aggregate by index with lambda function with [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and `join` (empty values in sample data are missing values)

```
df2 = df.groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: ' '.join(x.stack())).reset_index(name='Column1')
df2['Column1'] = df2.pop(0) + df2['Column1']
print (df2)

                                             Column1
0  Message 1:  Please do not smoke 15 mins nearby...
1  Message 2:  Parking lot on level is only for s...
2                                  Message 3:  /////
```